# Sprite does not appear in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a pong game which is basketball orientated. I'm trying to change the rectangles I currently have into basketball player sprites, to make it look more appealing. What happens is my player on the left side doesn't appear at all, and is invisible, but still functions as a block, and will hit the ball. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

```
import pygame

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

pygame.init()

size = 800,600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Basketball Shootout")

done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


class Player1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        """Constructor function"""
        # Call the parent's constructor
        super().__init__()

        # Set height, width
        self.image = pygame.Surface([15, 15])
        self.image = pygame.image.load("player1.png")



def player1(x1, y1, xsize, ysize):
    Player1(screen, [x1, y1, xsize, ysize])

def player2(x2, y2, xsize, ysize):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, [x2,y2,xsize,ysize])

def ball(ballx, bally):
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, [ballx,bally],20)

def Score1(score1):
    font = pygame.font.Font("Minecraft.ttf" ,50)
    text = font.render(str(score1), True, white)
    screen.blit(text, [160, 550])

def Score2(score2):
    font = pygame.font.Font("Minecraft.ttf" ,50)
    text = font.render(str(score2), True, white)
    screen.blit(text, [610, 550])

x1 = 20
y1 = 175
xsize = 35
ysize = 150
speed1 = 0

x2 = 740
y2 = 175
speed2 = 0

ballx = 550
bally = 250
speedx = 8
speedy = 5

score1 = 0
score2 = 0

bg = pygame.image.load("pongbg2.png")
rect1 = pygame.Rect(50,510,100,50)

def pausescreen():
    import pausescreen


display_game = True
game_page = 1


while not done: 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), rect1)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                speed1 = -15
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                speed1 = 15
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                speed2 = -15
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                speed2 = 15

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                speed1 = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                speed1 = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                speed2 = 0
            if event.key ==  pygame.K_DOWN:
                speed2 = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                pausescreen()




    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    player1(x1, y1, xsize, ysize)
    player2(x2, y2, xsize, ysize)
    ball(ballx,bally)
    Score1(score1)
    Score2(score2)

    y1 += speed1
    y2 += speed2
    ballx += speedx
    bally += speedy

    if y1 < 0:
        y1 = 0

    if y1 > 350:
        y1 = 350

    if y2 < 0:
        y2 = 0

    if y2 > 350:
        y2 = 350

    if ballx+20 > x2 and bally-20 > y2 and bally+20 < y2+ysize and ballx < x2+3:
        speedx = -speedx

    if ballx-20 < x1+35 and bally-20 > y1 and bally+20 < y1+ysize and ballx > x1+38:
        speedx = -speedx

    if bally > 477 or bally < 23:
        speedy = -speedy

    if ballx < 13:
        score2 += 1
        ballx = 350
        bally = 250

    if ballx > 750:
        score1 += 1
        ballx = 350
        bally = 250




    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Please read "[Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)". It might help if you tried to produce a [mcve]. You might stumble on what it is you're doing wrong that way and at least make your question easier to read.

Comment: I would advise you to edit your post to remove the last question. You can take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950906/java-pong-paddle-and-ball-collision-bug) which explains how to fix this common problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are not seeing the player on the left side, because you are not drawing it to the screen.

If you look at your code, for the most part, this is all the drawing code:

```
screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
player1(x1, y1, xsize, ysize)
player2(x2, y2, xsize, ysize)
ball(ballx,bally)
Score1(score1)
Score2(score2)
```

After looking at each function, the odd one out is `player1` which I suspect is the "player on the left". This function just calls the constructor of `Player1`:

```
def player1(x1, y1, xsize, ysize):
    Player1(screen, [x1, y1, xsize, ysize])
```

While the others actually something, such as, `player2`:

```
def player2(x2, y2, xsize, ysize):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, [x2,y2,xsize,ysize])
```

So my guess is this: change the function `player1` to `pygame.draw.rect(screen, x1, y1, xsize, ysize)`.

Edit: If you want to draw the image that you are loading in the `Player1` class try this code:

```
class Player1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        """Constructor function"""
        # Call the parent's constructor
        super().__init__()

        # Set height, width
        self.image = pygame.Surface([15, 15])
        self.image = pygame.image.load("player1.png")

    def draw(self, x1, y1):
       screen.blit(self.image, [x1, y1])
```

Then, just before the `while` loop you can initialize a `player1` object like this: `player1 = Player1(x1, y1)`.

Get rid of the `player1` *function*, and where you were previously calling `player1`, call the *method* `player1.draw(x1, y1)`.

Comment: Yeh that draws a rectangle but i'm trying to change the rectangle into a sprite (an image of a person)

Comment: @CianMc I've edited my post to include a code example of what you'd like to do. If this answers your question, please remember to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow). Thanks!